# Why doesn't it work when I place values from other lists into a new one and place the new list in an if statement?

Tags: python

```
Top1 = ["__|", "__|", "__"]
Middle1 = ["__|", "__|", "__"]
Bottom1 = ["  |", "  |", "  "]
V1 = [Top1[0], Middle1[0], Bottom1[0]]
V2 = [Top1[1], Middle1[1], Bottom1[1]]
V3 = [Top1[2], Middle1[2], Bottom1[2]]
D1 = [Top1[0], Middle1[1], Bottom1[2]]
D2 = [Top1[2], Middle1[1], Bottom1[0]]
```

These are the lists I have created in the initialization.

```
while game_on == True:
    if Bottom1 == [" o |"," o |"," o "] or Top1 == ["_o_|","_o_|","_o_"] or Middle1 == ["_o_|","_o_|","_o_"]:
        game_on = False
        print("The winner is player 2!")
    if Bottom1 == [" x |"," x |"," x "] or Top1 == ["_x_|","_x_|","_x_"] or Middle1 == ["_x_|","_x_|","_x_"]:
        game_on = False
        print("The winner is player 1!")
    if V1 == ["_o_|", "_o_|", " o |"] or V2 == ["_o_|", "_o_|", " o |"] or V3 == ["_o_", "_o_", " o "]:
        game_on = False
        print("The winner is player 2")
    if V1 == ["_x_|", "_x_|", " x |"] or V2 == ["_x_|", "_x_|", " x |"] or V3 == ["_x_", "_x_", " x "]:
        game_on = False
        print("The winner is player 1")
    if D1 == ["_o_|", "_o_|", " o "] or D2 == ["_o_", "_o_|", " o |"]:
        game_on = False
        print("The winner is player 2")
    if D1 == ["_x_|", "_x_|", " x "] or D2 == ["_x_", "_x_|", " x |"]:
        game_on = False
        print("The winner is player 1")
```

And this is the code in which I used lists V1 through D2. The problem is even when the input is matched up with the if statements that contain lists V1 through D2 they don't run their code and the game continues (as you may have figured out this is tic tac toe and I am a new coder).

Comment: ...What is this?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Looks like tic-tac-toe

Comment: When you assign `V1 = [Top1[0], Middle1[0], Bottom1[0]]`, the `V1` list has a copy of the elements from `Top1`, `Middle1`, and `Bottom1`. Changing `Top1[0]` won't change the corresponding element of `V1`.

Comment: What you have been writing looks like the "how not to do it tic tac toe example". The main problem here is that you did not divide the data from its representation. At first create a list of 3 lists of 3 `None` values as the board. Then fill it with 0 or 1 for the players. After that you should think about how to print the board from the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning elements from one list to another doesn't make a link between the lists, it copies the elements. So changing `Top1[0]` will not affect `V1[0]`.

You can solve this by changing the `Vx` and `Dx` arrays to functions that return a new list based on the current values of the arrays.

```
def getV1:
    return [Top1[0], Middle1[0], Bottom1[0]]
def getV2:
    return [Top1[1], Middle1[1], Bottom1[1]]
def getV3:
    return [Top1[2], Middle1[2], Bottom1[2]]
def getD1: 
    return [Top1[0], Middle1[1], Bottom1[2]]
def getD2:
    [Top1[2], Middle1[1], Bottom1[0]]
```

Then you can write:

```
while True:
    V1 = getV1()
    V2 = getV2()
    V3 = getV3()
    D1 = getD1()
    D2 = getD2()
    if V1 == ["_o_|", "_o_|", " o |"] or V2 == ["_o_|", "_o_|", " o |"] or V3 == ["_o_", "_o_", " o "]:
        print("The winner is player 2")
        break
    elif V1 == ["_x_|", "_x_|", " x |"] or V2 == ["_x_|", "_x_|", " x |"] or V3 == ["_x_", "_x_", " x "]:
        print("The winner is player 1")
        break
    elif D1 == ["_o_|", "_o_|", " o "] or D2 == ["_o_", "_o_|", " o |"]:
        print("The winner is player 2")
        break
    elif D1 == ["_x_|", "_x_|", " x "] or D2 == ["_x_", "_x_|", " x |"]:
        print("The winner is player 1")
        break
```

You should also use `elif`, so you don't bother checking for multiple winners. And it's more pythonic to use `while True:` for the loop and `break` to end it. I assume there's some other code before the tests that updates the game board lists, but you left that out of the question; otherwise this is an infinite loop.